# Marker Info Windows not opening

Tags: javascript, google-maps

iny the code which is below I have some info windows which display the data from the JSON file. I am having problemswhere InfoMarkers don't open when clicking on the markers. Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be great as this is all very new to me. Sorry if I am being a pain.

```
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.363, 175.044),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }; 

 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: value.altitude + value.hex
});



map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
mapOptions); 
window.setInterval(function() {
        readData();
     }, 1000);
}
 var marker = {};

function readData() {




 $.getJSON
('https://crossorigin.me/http://radar1.ddns.net:3080/data/aircraft.json', 
 function(data) {
  $.each(data.aircraft, function(i, value) {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon, value.flight, 
 value.altitude);
  if (marker[value.squawk]) {
    marker[value.squawk].setPosition(myLatlng);
    console.log("moving marker for " + value.squawk);
  } else {
    marker[value.squawk] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      icon: 'airplane.jpg',
      map: map,
      title: "Callsign   Altitude  " + value.flight + value.altitude
    });
    console.log("creating marker for " + value.squawk);
  }




            marker.addListener('click', function() {
infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }); 







        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You infoWindow is in the wrong place  ... try move the code before  the marker  listener

```
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: value.altitude + value.hex
  });

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should something like below.I have not implemented but you have to bind click event on each marker.

```
    var marker = {};
    var objMarker;
    $.each(data.aircraft, function(i, value) {

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "content here"
       });
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(value.lat, value.lon, value.flight, value.altitude);

        objMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          icon: 'airplane.jpg',
          map: map,
          title: "Callsign   Altitude  " + value.flight + value.altitude
        });
        marker.push(objMarker)

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function() {
             infowindow.open(map, marker[i]);
         });
    })
```